# Efficiently calculating permutations of chars of strings given the permuations of each string

Tags: string, algorithm

Consider a string list:
["a", "ab", "abc", "abd"， "abcd", ...]
where each subsequent string contains some portions of the previous string and
the list is sorted by the lengths of the strings.

The goal is to compute the permutations of chars of each string in the list and print them.
Will the permutation of chars of the previous string contributes to the calculations of the permutation of chars of the next string?
In other words, given 2 sets of permutations of the strings "abc", "de", is it possible to combine these permutations such that the result is the permutation of "abcde"?

Edit: If so, will it be faster than directly calculating the permutation of each string seperately?

Comment: It is possible, but it's not asymptotically faster if you want to output the numbers. What do you want to do with the result? Print it? Then you can just as well compute the new permutations. If you want to do something different with it (for example, count the number of permutations), then you can certainly reuse the subresults

Comment: Keep in mind, that in order to reuse previous permutation generation results, you most likely will have to keep these results in memory which, considering that number of permutations is n!, can take A LOT of memory, while generating next permutation is trivial and don't require any additional information in memory.